# How to save graph to .osm format with osmnx in python?

Tags: python, graph, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am using the python library osmnx to obtain a graph from an airport.
I can easily do it by using the following line of code:

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('wien flughafen austria', infrastructure='way["aeroway"]',simplify=False, custom_filter = ('["aeroway"~"taxiway|taxilane|parking_position"]'))
```

Now my goal is to save this file in the osm format so I can then opend it with another software called [Java OpenStreatMap Editor](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/)

In order to save the file I used the following line of code as suggested in the [osmnx documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
ox.save_load.save_as_osm(G, 'test.osm')
```

However this doesn't seem to work. Would you be able to suggest me the correct way to save the graoh to the osm format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using osmnx=0.11.1. The following should work.

```
ox.save_load.save_graph_osm(G, filename='test.osm')
```

Comment: I installed again osmnx from github and solved the issue :)

Comment: Btw do you know if it is possible to load such file in Java OpenStreatMap Editor? it seems to me it does not work...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with Java OSM Editor... but just to share, I was trying to load the saved 'osm' file in OSRM (a routing server tool), and it gave me error like 'missing version attribute', so I am not sure if you are facing similar issue in Jave OSM Editor. In the end, my solution is to download osm file directly from OpenStreetMap site, either by 'exporting' directly using the bounding box approach, or download from the archive. Both will provide osm files with complete attribute. Maybe you have a quick try with those files.

Comment: Is there something similar for the building footprints?

Comment: Note that in recent releases of OSMnx, the correct function call is ox.io.save_graph_xml(G, filepath). See [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.io.save_graph_xml) for details.

Answer (score 1):

regarding the building footprints that you asked in the comments above, you just do

```
GeoDataFrame.to_file("GeoDataFrame_name.shp")
```

and it is saved as a shapefile in your working directory